# displaying a chart in excel with (x,y) being an average as the starting value

Tags: excel, charts

Suppose I want to plot a chart in excel where the starting (x,y) coordinate should be the average and above average values will be displayed towards up and below average values will be displayed towards bottom (inverted). Check the picture below. I have sales data of potato year wise. The average value is 102.

[image]

the chart should look like somewhat as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it looks in Excel 2019 - you change 'Horizontal axis crosses' on the axis options:

[image]

If you need to show values below 102 as negative, I think you would have to subtract the average from the data.